# Latency doesn't work with PulseAudio on linux

Tags: pulseaudio

I have two speakers. The first one is connected to a PCI card and the second one via Bluetooth. Sounds are played a little bit earlier on the PCI card so I want to add some latency. I downloaded the pulse audio GUI and I have this :

[image]

As you can see, I added offset of 2 seconds on the "Audio Interne" (the PCI card).

I checked with the command `pactl list cards` and I have this for the internal card :

```
Card #1
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Owner Module: 8
        Properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7f10000 irq 27"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "1e20"
                device.product.name = "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Audio interne"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
                output:analog-stereo: Sortie Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Duplex stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-21: Sortie Surround analogique 2.1 (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Sortie Surround analogique 2.1 + Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-40: Sortie Surround analogique 4.0 (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Sortie Surround analogique 4.0 + Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-41: Sortie Surround analogique 4.1 (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Sortie Surround analogique 4.1 + Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-50: Sortie Surround analogique 5.0 (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Sortie Surround analogique 5.0 + Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-51: Sortie Surround analogique 5.1 (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: yes)
                output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Sortie Surround analogique 5.1 + Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: yes)
                output:iec958-stereo: Sortie Stéréo numérique (IEC958) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
                output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Sortie Stéréo numérique (IEC958) + Entrée Stéréo analogique (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: yes)
                off: Éteint (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        Active Profile: output:analog-stereo
        Ports:
                analog-input-front-mic: Microphone avant (priority: 8500, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analo
g-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                analog-input-rear-mic: Microphone arrière (priority: 8200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analo
g-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                analog-input-linein: Entrée ligne (priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analo
g-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                analog-output-lineout: Sortie ligne (priority: 9900, latency offset: 2000000 usec, available)
                        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+inp
ut:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
                analog-output-headphones: Casque audio (priority: 9000, latency offset: 2000000 usec, not available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                iec958-stereo-output: Sortie numérique (S/PDIF) (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
                        Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

And I tried to do `pactl play-sample bell.ogg alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`. It always seems instantaneous. The latency I set doesn't seems to change anything, even when I play music.

What can I do?

### EDIT

With `pactl list sinks`, I see this :

```
Latency: 2039815 usec, configured 40000 usec
```

So it seems the latency is set correctly but it seems to be instantaneous when I play a sound. I suppose there should be a delay. Is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the latency offset in your screenshot is just Pulsaudio calculating time to buffer sizes with given sample frequencies and trying to arrange this parameters with ALSA. Changing the latency offset there not showing an effect might just be an ALSA driver not supporting much variety in buffer sizes.

To get an extra buffer you could add a null sink to use [module-loobpack's](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index57h3) `latency_msec` like so:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=delayed
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=2000 source=delayed.monitor sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

Then you have to combine the null sink with your bluetooth audio.

I've had the expected huge delay when testing this simple setup without [module-combine-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index11h3) like this:

```
paplay someaudio.ext --device delayed
```

Comment: I tried to load the second device with `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=2000 source=delayed.monitor sink=bluez_sink.F8_DF_15_BB_6D_F5.a2dp_sink` so the `paplay` command send the sound to both devices but I still have the same problem. I tried with a single device but it's always instantaneous. I tried with other `latency_msec` but it doesn't change anything. Any idea?

Comment: finally it seems to works. I'm don't why it doesn't yesterday. I had to find the right accuracy with command line by doeing `pactl load-module` and `pactl unload-module` each time. Do you have a more convenient way? A graphical tool would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a graphical tool for that. But for loading and unloading you could do something like `index=$( pactl load-module ... ); sleep 5; pactl unload-module $index`

Answer (score 0):

You need the latency on the Haut-parluer (Speaker), not the Sortei ligne (Line Out or Headphone Jack). Or, you could put the latency on both as long as the bluetooth is not a device plugged into the head phone jack, as this would further increase the latency.

- The sound would be instantaneous, because the latency for the internal speakers is 0. Yet the head phone jacks is 2 seconds.

Comment: I tried different settings and it never take the latency. The sound is always instantaneous. I tried to set the latency as you said but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Weird, wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler, 1-line form of [the solution with `module-loopback`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495369/524752) that doesn't use extra modules or sinks:

```bash
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=2000 source=bluez_sink.F8_DF_15_BB_6D_F5.a2dp_sink.monitor sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

The source should be the Bluetooth device, and the sink should be the device you want to delay. Then just select the Bluetooth device in the system tray or in your case, in `pactl play-sample bell.ogg bluez_sink.F8_DF_15_BB_6D_F5.a2dp_sink.monitor`, and you should be good to go. The only disadvantage is that the volume buttons only control the Bluetooth device, and the GUI can't select just the uncombined Bluetooth device anymore. Everything is accomplished in one step with `module-loopback`, and there is no need for an extra `module-combine-sink` nor `module-null-sink`.